# encode/decode image with base64 breaks image

Tags: javascript, fileapi

I am trying to encode and decode an image. I am using the FileReader's readAsDataURL method to convert the image to base64. Then to convert it back I have tried using  `readAsBinaryString()` and `atob()` with no luck. Is there another way to persist images without base64 encoding them?

> **readAsBinaryString()**
>
> Starts reading the contents of the specified Blob, which may be a
>   File. When the read operation is finished, the readyState will become
>   DONE, and the onloadend callback, if any, will be called. At that
>   time, the result attribute contains the raw binary data from the file.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

**Sample Code**
http://jsfiddle.net/qL86Z/3/

```
$("#base64Button").on("click", function () {
    var file = $("#base64File")[0].files[0]
    var reader = new FileReader();

    // callback for readAsDataURL
    reader.onload = function (encodedFile) {
        console.log("reader.onload");
        var base64Image = encodedFile.srcElement.result.split("data:image/jpeg;base64,")[1];
        var blob = new Blob([base64Image],{type:"image/jpeg"});
        var reader2 = new FileReader();

        // callback for readAsBinaryString
        reader2.onloadend = function(decoded) {
            console.log("reader2.onloadend");
            console.log(decoded); // this should contain binary format of the image

            // console.log(URL.createObjectURL(decoded.binary)); // Doesn't work
        };
        reader2.readAsBinaryString(blob);

        // console.log(URL.createObjectURL(atob(base64Image))); // Doesn't work

    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    console.log(URL.createObjectURL(file)); // Works
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: in which browser does this example work? TypeError: encodedFile.srcElement is undefined

Comment: I am using Chrome for testing, but I'll need it to work in the latest Android and iOS browsers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After some more research I found the answer from [here](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s18/sh/50ea8199-3f8c-4061-8c90-82e264380412/2c92f01382e0b35e1a48fd8e173ac8b2?noteKey=2c92f01382e0b35e1a48fd8e173ac8b2&noteGuid=50ea8199-3f8c-4061-8c90-82e264380412)
I basically needed to wrap the raw binary in an arraybuffer and convert the binary chars to Unicode.

This is the code that was missing,

```
    var binaryImg = atob(base64Image);
    var length = binaryImg.length;
    var ab = new ArrayBuffer(length);
    var ua = new Uint8Array(ab);
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        ua[i] = binaryImg.charCodeAt(i);
    }
```

The full sample code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qL86Z/8/)

Answer (score 1):

[`URL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.URL.createObjectURL) expects a [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Blob) (which can be a [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/File)) as its argument. Not a string. That's why `URL.createObjectURL(file)` works.

Instead, you are creating a [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileReader) `reader` that reads `file` as a *data url*, then you use that data url to create another `Blob` (with the same contents). And then you even create a `reader2` to get a *binary string* from the just constructed `blob`. However, neither the `base64Image` url string part (even if `btoa`-decoded to a larger string) nor the `decoded.binary` string are vaild arguments to `URL.createObjectURL`!

Comment: Is it possible to convert `base64Image` back into the original file though? I'm basically trying to undo what `reader.readAsDataURL(file);` does with `readAsBinaryString()` or `atob()`.

Comment: `var blob = new Blob([base64Image],{type:"image/jpeg"});` should do it? Try `URL.createObjectURL(blob);`

Comment: It shows a broken image for `URL.createObjectURL(blob);` I updated the JSFiddle here, http://jsfiddle.net/qL86Z/7/

Here's a screencast showing the broken image.
http://screencast.com/t/vVVGNTvo