# How to upload a picture to a document server via ajax and cmis

Tags: jquery, ajax, cmis

I'm trying to perform a POST request containing a picture to a document server via ajax out of my mobile JavaScript application.

My ajax call with the required cmis data looks like the following:

```
var cmisInfo = {
  'objectId': parentFolder,
  'cmisaction': 'createDocument',
  'propertyId[0]': 'cmis:name',
  'propertyValue[0]': filename,
  'propertyId[1]': 'cmis:objectTypeId',
  'propertyValue[1]': 'cmis:document'
};


$.ajax(rootFolder, {
  type: 'POST',
  data: cmisInfo,
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', csrfToken);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Basic dXNlcjpwdw==");
  }
}).done(function(response) {
  console.log("New File ID: " + response.properties["cmis:objectId"].value);
}).fail(function(jqXHR) {
  console.log(jqXHR.responseJSON.message);
});
```

The picture im trying to upload is present as a `BASE64` string, fetched with a `FileReader`. Lets assume it's saved in the following variable:

```
var pictureBase64; // containing picture from filesystem in BASE64
```

My question now is, where to put `pictureBase64` as content in my request? I suppose that such an object would be sent along in the `data` attribute within the ajax call normally, but in my case the data attribute is already used for the required cmis information. How can I send both?

Any help or hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14988118) and [here](http://scn.sap.com/community/mobile-documents/blog/2014/10/31/new-guides-available-about-how-to-develop-custom-java-and-javascript-clients-for-sap-mobile-documents#comment-584279).

To upload a picture from the file system to a document server, I had to send the data as `FormData` in the `ajax` call and append the image data like the following:

```
formData = new FormData;
formData.append('objectid', parentFolder);
formData.append('cmisaction', 'createDocument');
formData.append('propertyId[0]', 'cmis:name');
formData.append('propertyValue[0]', filename);
formData.append('propertyId[1]', 'cmis:objectTypeId');
formData.append('propertyValue[1]', 'cmis:document');
formData.append('_charset_', 'UTF-8');
formData.append('media', newBlob);
```

The `newBlob` is converted from the original `pictureBase64`, containing the image data as a base64 string:

```
cleanBase64 = pictureBase64.match(/,(.*)$/)[1];
binaryImage = atob(cleanBase64);
arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(binaryImage.length);
uintArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
i = 0;
while (i < binaryImage.length) {
  uintArray[i] = binaryImage.charCodeAt(i);
  i++;
}
blob = new Blob([uintArray], {
  type: "image/jpeg"
});
newBlob = blob.slice(0, blob.size, "image/jpeg");
```

At last `processData: false` and `contentType: false` have to be added to the `ajax`call to make it work.