# Getting wrong file encoding(?) after streaming from php to client through ajax

Tags: php, laravel, character-encoding

Using laravel I am sending binary data to client, which is later being saved to client's machine.
I am using ajax and streaming the contents.
This is what I send from the server:

```php
$fileRecord = File::findOrFail($fileId);
set_time_limit(0);

$fs = Storage::disk('local')->getDriver();
$metaData = $fs->getMetadata($fileRecord->getFilePath());
$fileStream = $fs->readStream($fileRecord->getFilePath());

return response()->stream(function () use ($fileStream) {
    while(@ob_end_clean());
    fpassthru($fileStream);
}, 200, [
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'binary',
    'Content-Type'              => $metaData['type'],
    'Content-Disposition'       => "attachment; filename=\"{$fileRecord->getFullFileName()}\"",
]);
```

I solved couple of problems related to size of data, like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36778167/download-from-laravel-storage-without-loading-whole-file-in-memory).

But I cannot get the proper content of files on the client. I tried saving content to a different file on the server and everything works fine.

Here is the sample of what I am getting (*samples list a piece of file from beginning until a certain character*):

Ex 1. `png` image

This is what it should be:

```
89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A 00 00 00 0D 49 48 44 52 00 00 06 40 00 00 04 B0 08 02 00 00 00 2C 63 11 C0 00 00 00 04 67 41 4D 41 00 00 D6 D8 D4 4F 58 32 00 00 00 19 74 45 58 74 53 6F 66 74 77 61 72 65 00 41 64 6F 62 65 20 49 6D 61 67 65 52 65 61 64 79 71 C9 65 3C 00 07 8D 52 49 44 41 54
```

This is what is being generated:

*copied from devTools into file*:

```
C2 89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A 00 00 00 0D 49 48 44 52 00 00 06 40 00 00 04 C2 B0 08 02 00 00 00 2C 63 11 C3 80 00 00 00 04 67 41 4D 41 00 00 C3 96 C3 98 C3 94 4F 58 32 00 00 00 19 74 45 58 74 53 6F 66 74 77 61 72 65 00 41 64 6F 62 65 20 49 6D 61 67 65 52 65 61 64 79 71 C3 89 65 3C 00 07 C2 8D 52 49 44 41 54
```

*after browser downloaded data as a file on client*:

```
EF BF BD 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A 00 00 00 0D 49 48 44 52 00 00 06 40 00 00 04 EF BF BD 08 02 00 00 00 2C 63 11 EF BF BD 00 00 00 04 67 41 4D 41 00 00 EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 4F 58 32 00 00 00 19 74 45 58 74 53 6F 66 74 77 61 72 65 00 41 64 6F 62 65 20 49 6D 61 67 65 52 65 61 64 79 71 EF BF BD 65 3C 00 07 EF BF BD 52 49 44 41 54
```

Ex 2. `pdf` file

This is what it should be:

```
25 50 44 46 2D 31 2E 35 0D 0A 25 B5 B5 B5 B5 0D 0A 31 20 30 20 6F 62 6A 0D 0A 3C 3C 2F 54 79 70 65 2F 43 61 74 61 6C 6F 67 2F 50 61 67 65 73 20 32 20 30 20 52 2F 4C 61 6E 67 28 65 6E 2D 55 53 29 20 2F 53 74 72 75 63 74 54 72 65 65 52 6F 6F 74 20 33 31
```

This is what is being generated:

*manually copied from devTools into file*:

```
25 50 44 46 2D 31 2E 35 0D 0A 25 C2 B5 C2 B5 C2 B5 C2 B5 0D 0A 31 20 30 20 6F 62 6A 0D 0A 3C 3C 2F 54 79 70 65 2F 43 61 74 61 6C 6F 67 2F 50 61 67 65 73 20 32 20 30 20 52 2F 4C 61 6E 67 28 65 6E 2D 55 53 29 20 2F 53 74 72 75 63 74 54 72 65 65 52 6F 6F 74 20 33 31
```

*after browser downloaded data as a file on client*:

```
25 50 44 46 2D 31 2E 35 0D 0A 25 EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 0D 0A 31 20 30 20 6F 62 6A 0D 0A 3C 3C 2F 54 79 70 65 2F 43 61 74 61 6C 6F 67 2F 50 61 67 65 73 20 32 20 30 20 52 2F 4C 61 6E 67 28 65 6E 2D 55 53 29 20 2F 53 74 72 75 63 74 54 72 65 65 52 6F 6F 74 20 33 31
```

Some of the headers I get on the client (chrome devTools):

For png file:

```
Content-Disposition:attachment;filename="8c4d44a0-3bd9-11e7-8e6a-4ff287c4841c.png"
Content-Length:739993
Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary
Content-Type:image/png; charset=utf-8
```

For pdf file:

```
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="e88fd450-3bd8-11e7-9dfa-99b21f936329.pdf"
Content-Length:420639
Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary
Content-Type:application/pdf; charset=utf-8
```

P.S. You can see there is a `C2` character or `EF BF BD` character sequence throughout the malformed data. So it seems to me that this is an encoding issue. I tried to use `utf8_encode` on the string, but to no avail. `mb_detect_encoding` on file handle returns blank string.

What am I doing wrong?

P.P.S. On client I use binary data I got from ajax in the following way:

```js
saveAs(new Blob([ajaxData], { type: mimeType }), fileName);
```

I use [Blob.js](https://github.com/bjornstar/blob-polyfill) and [saveAs](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what it was.
Apparantly you cannot directly feed the binary data into the `Blob` object in javascript (at least for pdfs, pngs, jpegs it does not work), but have to use something like this:

```js
function binaryToUint8Arr (bin) {
    var length = bin.length;
    var buf = new ArrayBuffer(length);
    var arr = new Uint8Array(buf);
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        arr[i] = bin.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return buf;
}
```

I found this solution [here](https://bl.ocks.org/nolanlawson/0eac306e4dac2114c752), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14988118/1095951) person says that:

> I basically needed to *wrap the raw binary in an arraybuffer* and
>   convert the *binary chars to Unicode*

So my code becomes:

```js
saveAs(new Blob([binaryToUint8Arr(ajaxData)], { type: mimeType }), fileName);
```

(where `ajaxData` is binary data I got from ajax)